# function called infinite times in react while inView

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';


const About = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    
  });
  
 
  
    if(inView)  {navigate('/#about')}

  
  return (
    <div ref={ref}  className='about-container' id="about">
      
      
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `navigate('/#about')` directly which causes a loop for that component re-rendering.
The fix could be

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';


const About = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    
  });
  
   //when your `inView` value change, you change hash
   useEffect(() => {
      if(inView)  {navigate('/#about')}
   }, [inView])
  
    

  
  return (
    <div ref={ref}  className='about-container' id="about">
      
      
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Comment: i tried this it doesnt work. maybe because about ins seccont section . and wont be visible when initially dom renders

Comment: Could you try to add dependancy `inView` for `useEffect`. That is also a possible fix, because it only listens to `inView` value change @SalilRajkarnikar

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your getting stuck in an infinite loop because of this line

```
if(inView)  {navigate('/#about')}
```

When the `About` component loads it shows your div with the `#about` id causing it to be inView. This in turn calls navigate which takes you to the `#about` div again, repeating over and over again.

From my understanding the `inView` hook should be used to record metrics like how often someone scrolls past a certain point or to trigger some sort of Javascript code like showing a modal when someone gets to the bottom of the page. You could always use it to navigate to a new component just not the same one.